# Procesar json_encode($data) a través de ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy trabajando con ajax, jquery y php; envío una solicitud ajax a php a través de post, de la siguiente forma:

```
function obtenermail() {
    //console.log($('#destinatario').val());
    var ced = $('#destinatario').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'cedula': $('#destinatario').val()},
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>"+"/roles/obtenercorreo", 
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
}
```

en php tengo la siguiente función:

```
public function obtenercorreo(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logueado')){
        $ced = $this->input->post('cedula');
        $data = $this->persona_model->getPersonaced($ced);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        redirect('','refresh');
    }
}
```

La petición funciona correctamente, me muestra el arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
[{"cedula":"1100253986","nombres":"SOTO CASTILLO LAURO HERNAN","mod_laboral":"CONTRATO COLECTIVO","email":""}]
```

Lo que no sé, es cómo obtener cada valor por separado, ya que si pongo

```
console.log(data[0])
console.log(data.cedula)
console.log(data['cedula'])
```

me devuelve **undefined** o una **cadena vacía**.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo podría hacer para leer cada elemento individual?**
es decir obtener la cedula, o el correo por separado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahora mismo lo está tratando como si fuera una cadena, debes validar/procesar esa cadena como JSON (con `JSON.parse`) y entonces podrás acceder a los datos de manera sencilla.

Los cambios en el código JavaScript serían así:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'cedula': $('#destinatario').val()},
    url: "<?php echo site_url();?>"+"/roles/obtenercorreo", 
    success : function(data) {
        var datos = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(datos[0].cedula);
        console.log(datos[0].email);
    }
});
```

Y ahora en la consola debería aparecer el valor correcto de la cédula y el correo.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, funcionó a la perfeccion.

Answer (score 5):

Pese a ya tener la solución, te doy una recomendación (carita feliz).

El siguiente código contiene una llamada AJAX a la URL que deseas y la solución que te planteo @Alvaro Montoro. Para mejorar la práctica de tu petición, te recomiendo que añadas en tu código sólo 2 líneas y borres 1.

La primer línea a añadir será en Js, debido a que le dirás a jQuery que tipo de contenido esperas (en este caso JSON) así te evitas parsear el dato debido a que lo recibes como tal (en JSON).

## Solución

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'cedula': $('#destinatario').val() },
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/roles/obtenercorreo", 
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].cedula);
        console.log(data[0].email);
    }
});
```

La segunda línea es en el lado del servidor, lo que hace es devolver en la petición el tipo de contenido que contiene la respuesta (JSON).

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Gracias ese este tipo de prácticas, puedes detectar errores como cuando el servidor no te responda un JSON para manejarlo de distinta forma, que en dicho caso, se activaría la función **error** del AJAX.

Comment: Esta solución está muy bien

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, siempre es bueno tener más alternativas, lo tendré presente, gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Te puedes ahorrar una línea de esta forma:

```
success : function(data) {
        console.log(data.cedula);
        console.log(data.email);
    }
```